# Congratulations to Kilisi on 100k reputation!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations on 100k!

[image: Kilisi]

You have a very interesting, direct style. And you have provided a lot of great answers.

Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Congratulations Kilisi! Much deserved milestone to our Zen master.

Comment: He beat me! I guess that's what I get for taking a long break :D Congrats to yet another of the 100k club here!

Answer (score 32):

Thanks, it's made my day.

It's been a pretty uniformly good experience here for me over the years, I've learnt a lot and had a few laughs. There's a lot of intelligent, experienced and insightful people here, glad to be part of it.

Comment: Do you have any post you are particularly proud of? Perhaps one you consider the most valuable...

Comment: @DarkCygnus not really, I did have one answer that had me almost choking on my coffee. But it quite rightfully got deleted.

Comment: This is like your longest answer ;) but honestly good stuff, I typically find myself upvoting your answers

Comment: @Tas actually one day over The Watercooler I recall Monica or someone else did a query to find out Kilisi's longest answer... and IIRC it was actually longer than this one

Comment: @DarkCygnus my English isn't great so I keep the answers short... at least I don't use abbreviations :)

Comment: There was one answer longer today at least by a huge margin :)

Comment: Every time I see someone who writes fluent English say "my English isn't great" I smile a little. Honestly I have never once thought English wasn't your first language. Well, other than those silly British English spellings ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Seconded!

Often a concise and to the point answer is just what people need and you thoroughly deserve to join the 100k+ club and FWIW you've always come across as an interesting and genuine person.

Here's to the next 100k!

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely my favorite poster.  No nonsense straight to the point.  Every time.

Answer (score 2):

Some people just need a fair bit of brutal honesty and this guy never fails to bring just that.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations from me as well @Kilisi. Your answers are very often my favorite. Hope to see you around for many more contributions to come.